# Exponential Posteriori with a Uniform Prior

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I'm studyng for a final exam and found this problem from another generation, but I don't know how I should continue... I will be gratefull for any help, thanks you.

Let be $X|\theta\sim U(0,\theta)$ and the prior $\pi(\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta}I_{(0,\infty)(\theta)}$. Find $p(\theta|{\bf x})$.

I managed so far to do this

$\begin{eqnarray}
p(\theta| {\bf x}) &\propto& p({\bf{x}}|\theta)p(\theta) \\
&=& \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\theta}I(0<x_{i}<\theta) \right]\left[ \theta e^{-\theta}I(0<\theta<\infty) \right] \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\theta^{n}}\theta e^{-\theta}I(0<x_{(1)})I(x_{(n)}<\theta)I(0<\theta<\infty) \\
&\propto& \theta^{1-n}e^{-\theta}I(x_{(n)}<\theta<\infty),
\end{eqnarray}$

with $x_{(1)}$, $x_{(n)}$ the minimum an maximun respectively. Because I can't identify the distribution, we have to find the normalizing constant. That is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\theta^{1-n}e^{-\theta}I(x_{(n)}<\theta<\infty) d\theta=\int_{x_{(n)}}^{\infty}\theta^{1-n}e^{-\theta}d\theta. $$

But I fail to see how to obtain a clossed form for that integral. Of course, if we want to find the full conditional instead and try to find the marignal distribution of ${\bf X}$, we will have to deal with the same integral too. I thought to express it as a incomplete gamma function but $1-n<0$ if $n>1$, which of course always will be satisfied in a practic situation.

Comment: Nothing in the question refers to anything that might correspond to your "$n.$"  Where did that come from??  In the question $X$ is explicitly a univariate random variable and so is $\theta.$

Comment: Good point... in that case we have exp(-theta) I(x<theta, Inf), and that is a exponential with the location parameter x. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is NOT an exponential since it is truncated from below by $x$.

Comment: The normalizing constant (with n=1) as in the question) is $\exp(-x)$